# div position for Background image

Tags: css, html, position

on the site [JN-Racing](http://www.jn-racing.de) i´ve add a div on the left side but when I resize the Browser the div goes about the content. Thanks for all tipps

Comment: what browser are you using?   everything looks ok to me in chrome and even in IE 9

Comment: can you clarify the problem? I see how the fixed div on the left causes problems with the main content, but what would you like it to do?

Comment: I would the backgtround(the left image ) beside the content on the left side spaceless direct beside the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#bg_right {
    background-image: url("images/bg_rechts.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: right;
    height: 935px;
    position: relative;
    width: 258px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#bg_left {
    background-image: url("images/bg_links.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 935px;
    position: relative;
    width: 258px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#wrapper {
    height: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 1024px;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1540px;
}
```

If you limit the width of the body, it shall work like a charm! (:

Comment: thank you veeery much !, I got also the same situation on the right side one moment i put the div with the image online

Comment: I add the div names bg_right how can i add it on the right side of the content ?

Comment: soory my bad, i´ve change the image name.
I took the same Position like the left element

Comment: Done, look at the changes I made, added "#bg_right" and in #wrapper  i added height 0.

Comment: Can I have your e mail ? :) Or Facebook ?